# For loop over a DenseVector does not work

Tags: java, list, scala, scala-breeze

I am using a function returning a [DenseVector](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/blob/master/math/src/main/scala/breeze/linalg/DenseVector.scala) but since yesterday I am not able to read its values as before. Here is the snippet:

```
val clusters = stsc()
for (i <- 0 until clusters.length) {
    print(clusters(i))
}
```

It returns `java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: List(method apply$mcI$sp, method apply$mcI$sp)`.

But this snippet works:

```
val clusters = stsc()
clusters.foreach { print }
```

And the illogical thing is that this snippet also runs:

```
val clusters = stsc()
clusters.foreach { print }
for (i <- 0 until clusters.length) {
    print(clusters(i))
}
```

`stsc()` always returns the same DenseVector. I do not understand why the first snipped does not work, it seems to me like a bug from Scala. Is there a way to get around it? I am using Scala 2.11.8.

Comment: You might actually be right regarding the Scala bug, I'm not quite sure though if it is really the same issue: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9578

Comment: OK so I will return a List instead of a DenseVector then.